# Ubuntu 19.04 high power consumption with intel integrated graphics

Tags: power-management, battery, powertop

**Aero 17 laptop w/ 9750H processor, nvidia gtx 1660ti, 1080P 144hz monitor**

Windows 10 reports 8 hours of battery life
Ubuntu 19.04 reports 2 hours

In Ubuntu 19.04, reporting sky-high 30-40 watt discharge at idle with integrated graphics.

Tested: kernel 5.0.x vs. 5.1.x

Tested: Brightness to lowest setting

Tested: 144hz vs 60hz refresh

Tested: Airplane mode

Tested: powertop --auto-tune

**Still consistently between 30-40 watt discharge at idle**

Here is the kicker... if I switch to nvidia graphics via prime-select, the power consumption drops to 16-22watts at idle. Almost seems like the high power consumption lies with intel integrated graphics, but that sounds a bit crazy.

I tried to disable the nvidia graphics card in the bios, but doesn't seem to be an option in the bios interface.

Any recommendations? Thanks in advance.

### Powerstat output

```
  Time    User  Nice   Sys  Idle    IO  Run Ctxt/s  IRQ/s Fork Exec Exit  Watts  pch_ca iwlwif acpitz x86_pk  CPU Freq  GPU W
22:48:01   0.3   0.6   0.2  98.9   0.0    1    532    370   14   12   25   -nanE  48.00  40.00  27.80  45.00  1.61 GHz   0.01
22:48:11   0.2   0.0   0.1  99.7   0.0    1    367    217    0    0    2  33.86   47.00  39.00  27.80  45.00  0.80 GHz   0.00
22:48:21   0.6   0.0   0.2  99.2   0.0    1    980    553    0    0    0  34.88   48.00  40.00  27.80  43.00  1.37 GHz   0.08
22:48:31   0.4   0.0   0.2  99.4   0.0    1    823    473    1    0    0  34.09   48.00  38.00  27.80  44.00  0.80 GHz   0.01
22:48:41   0.2   0.0   0.1  99.7   0.0    1    542    337    2    0    8  35.59   48.00  40.00  27.80  43.00  1.31 GHz   0.01
22:48:51   0.2   0.0   0.2  99.6   0.0    1    713    459   11    1   12  34.29   46.00  39.00  27.80  43.00  0.80 GHz   0.00
22:49:01   0.4   0.0   0.1  99.5   0.0    1    541    389    1    0   22  34.82   46.00  40.00  27.80  43.00  1.52 GHz   0.01
22:49:11   0.2   0.0   0.1  99.6   0.0    1    560    328    3    0    0  33.84   46.00  39.00  27.80  43.00  0.80 GHz   0.00
22:49:21   0.2   0.0   0.1  99.7   0.0    1    442    262    0    0    2  34.42   46.00  40.00  27.80  42.00  1.42 GHz   0.01
^C-------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ---- ---- ------  ------ ------ ------ ------ --------- ------
 Average   0.3   0.1   0.2  99.5   0.0  1.0  611.1  376.6  3.6  1.4  7.9  34.47   47.00  39.44  27.80  43.44  1.16 GHz   0.01
 GeoMean   0.3   0.0   0.1  99.5   0.0  1.0  585.9  362.8  0.0  0.0  0.0  34.47   46.99  39.44  27.80  43.43  1.11 GHz   0.01
  StdDev   0.1   0.2   0.0   0.3   0.0  0.0  182.0   99.9  4.9  3.7  9.2   0.53    0.94   0.68   0.00   0.96  0.33 GHz   0.02
-------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ---- ---- ------  ------ ------ ------ ------ --------- ------
 Minimum   0.2   0.0   0.1  98.9   0.0  1.0  366.7  217.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  33.84   46.00  38.00  27.80  42.00  0.80 GHz   0.00
 Maximum   0.6   0.6   0.2  99.7   0.0  1.0  979.5  552.9 14.0 12.0 25.0  35.59   48.00  40.00  27.80  45.00  1.61 GHz   0.08
-------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ---- ---- ------  ------ ------ ------ ------ --------- ------
Summary:
System:  34.47 Watts on average with standard deviation 0.53  
GPU:   0.01 Watts on average with standard deviation 0.02  
Note: Power calculated from battery capacity drain, may not be accurate.


C-State    Resident      Count Latency 
C10         96.677%      30301     890
C9           0.106%        539     480
C8           2.261%      10202     200
C7s          0.002%         18     124
C6           0.271%       4707      85
C3           0.011%        782      70
C1E          0.027%        943      10
C1           0.027%        439       2
POLL         0.000%         41       0
C0           0.619%
```

### PowerTop Output

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 36.8 W
The power consumed was 0.00 J
The estimated remaining time is 1 hours, 37 minutes

Summary: 796.7 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/seconds, 0.0 VFS ops/sec and 9.1% CPU use

                Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
            316.5 µs/s     170.6        Timer          tick_sched_timer
             21.9 ms/s     124.6        Process        [PID 4719] powertop
              0.0 µs/s      0.00        Process        [PID 1954] /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
              5.8 ms/s     114.1        Interrupt      PS/2 Touchpad / Keyboard / Mouse
              8.3 ms/s      65.2        Process        [PID 1886] /usr/bin/gnome-shell
```

Comment: It seems the high power consumption is due to both cards drawing power at the same time. NVIDIA might not be completely turned off while not in use. Please [edit] your question with more info on how you switch between the two GPUs, do you do it from the BIOS or from NVIDIA prime. `TLP` while not a direct answer to your issue, but it could help. To try it please refer to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1160001/968501

Comment: Raffa, ive updated the question. I hadn't considered that both gpus may be drawing power at the same time. This makes a lot more sense as a potential culprit. Thanks for the link. Looking now.

Comment: When on Intel does this report anything?  `lsmod |grep nvidia`  (- here on my optimus laptop Intel at idle is reported as using a bit more than nvidia at idle though neither is over mid 20

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the suggestions @Raffa. It helped me discover this solution, which brought my power consumption from 30+ to 10 watts. Definitely has to do with Nvidia gpu drawing power even when Intel integrated is selected.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1145796/1002029

1. make sure Intel integrated is enabled using prime-select intel, then execute:

```
sudo -i
modprobe bbswitch
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF
```