# `prime-select intel` doesn't power off the NVIDIA GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I have a Dell XPS 15 9560 laptop with an Nvidia GTX 1050 graphics card. I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 with `nvidia-driver-440`.

When I run `prime-select intel` and reboot, `prime-select query` prints `intel` as expected, but `powertop` shows the NVIDIA GPU running at 100%, and the laptop is hot. The same happens in `on-demand` mode.

The [existing question's accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1145796/447822) is for Ubuntu 18.04 and doesn't fix my problem, since `sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF` returns `tee: /proc/acpi/bbswitch: No such file or directory`.

How to power off the NVIDIA GPU, using the proprietary driver?

Answer (score 0):

In order to run `sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF`, you will first have to install bbswitch. You can do this on Ubuntu 20 with

```
sudo apt install bbswitch-dkms
```

Followed by a reboot of your system.

If it still doesn't work, try running

```
sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/bbswitch.conf <<<bbswitch
```

And then reboot again (That modules-load line is to ensure that bbswitch is initialized on boot)

Warning: On some systems, bbswitch crashes the computer on boot, giving you a black screen. From grub, instead of pressing "enter" to select your OS, press "e" to edit the boot parameters. At the end of the line that starts with `linux`, append  `modprobe.blacklist=bbswitch`. After reboot, `sudo apt remove bbswitch-dkms`. You'll likely have to give up trying to use bbswitch at this point.